# 3-column join table generated for simple ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, many-to-many

I'm using these entities with JPA+Hibernate:

```
@Entity
public class Game {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="Game_admins")
    private Set<User> admins = new HashSet<User>();

    ...

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    ...
```

Thus far everything works well. Hibernate generates a join table called `Game_admins` with two colums, `Game_id` and `admins_id`.

However, if I add this to `User`:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="admins")
private Set<Game> adminForGames = new HashSet<Game>();
```

The join table suddenly gets three columns, one of which is `adminForGames_id`. I don't need or want that, and I don't think it should be generated since I specify `mappedBy`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to set the inverseJoin attriubtes

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="Game_admins", joinColumns = {
      @JoinColumn(name="admins_id")           
  },
inverseJoinColumns = {
  @JoinColumn(name="Game_id")
}
private Set<User> admins = new HashSet<User>();
```